# RESTful API for large "mash up" data pulls?

Tags: api, rest

I have recently been tasked with a small project of setting up a periodic (somewhere between daily & weekly) data dump from an internal database to a 3rd party product.  This project dovetails nicely with my company's desire (one which I share) to start standing up a formal service layer/API over the top of our data.

My personal preference is that those APIs should take on the form of RESTful endpoints - however, now I have what I think is a big design question - let me explain...

Looking at the data pull in question, it's hardly complicated.  If I were just going to construct a one-off query, it would conceptually look a little something like:

```
select o.order_num, o.order_date, p.product_description, sr.sales_rep_name
from order o, line_item li, product p, sales_rep sr
where li.order_num = o.order_num
  and li.product_id = p.product_id
  and sr.sales_rep_id = o.sales_rep_id
  and o.order_date >= [some arbitrary date]
```

Flipping my brain into "Resource Mode", I can think about how to convert this basic data model into URI's/payloads without too much trouble:

```
GET /orders/123
{ 
  "order_num": 59324, 
  "order_date": "2014-07-07", 
  "sales_rep_uri": "/salesRep/34",
  "line_items_uri": "/order/123/lineItems"
}
```

Getting more information about the sales rep:

```
GET /salesRep/34
{
  "sales_rep_name": "Jane Doe",
  "open_orders_uri": "/salesRep/34/orders"
}
```

Getting more information about line items:

```
GET /orders/123/lineItems
{
  "line_items": [
    {"order_uri": "/order/123", "product_uri": "/products/68"},
    {"order_uri": "/order/123", "product_uri": "/products/99"}
  ]
}
```

And so on.  I'm *not* saying it's a perfect API, I'm just trying to demonstrate it's not exactly rocket science to go about thinking how you might express the data model in a nicely normalized, resource-oriented type of way via RESTful URIs.  But that is exactly where the design question comes into play...

On one hand, I can crank out a query to solve the problem very easily, but the very nature of queries requires the various domain concepts to be tightly coupled (in other words, utilizing joins to bring all of the normalized data together into one nice, custom-purpose de-normalized structure).

On the other hand, going through the mental process of thinking out a RESTful API leads me right back down that road of keeping things nicely compartmentalized - e.g. asking for "Order 123" shouldn't send me back this huge graph where I can see the full product description, the sales rep's phone number, etc, etc.  The concept of a full blown HATEOAS-level RESTful API dictates consumers should be making subsequent GETs to drill down for that kind of detail only as-needed.

My question boils down to this: solving this use case seems really easy to do with a direct query and really difficult to do against a nice & tidy RESTful API (I'm picturing the literally 1000's of individual GETs it would take for me to assemble a weeks worth of data vs the few seconds it would take for the query to run).  Is there some elegant subtlety of good RESTful design that I don't understand that would prevent me from seeing a good solution, or am I trying to fit a round peg into a square hole (i.e. REST is not good at pulling big data batches across multiple resources)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this out there as a potential solution:

Conceptually, I treat the results of this query as a resource unto itself - like "orderReport".

Treating this as it's own resource, the API could behave something like:

```
GET /orderReport/[some arbitrary date]
```

You could then send back either a `201 Created` (if the query is relatively quick running) with a location header like `Location: /orderReport/[GUID]`.  Alternatively, if the query takes a while to run (I honestly don't know if it does or not off the top of my head), you could send back a `202 Accepted` with a location header of `Location: /orderReport/[GUID]/status`.

You could then do follow up GETs against those URLs to get either the report status (`200 OK` if still processing without error, `201 Created` with location header pointing to the report URL if its done) or the report itself.

There's nothing to say the report data couldn't also incorporate HATEOAS in addition to the data strictly needed to fulfill the use case requirements, like:

```
{
  [
    {
       "order_num": 123,
       "order_uri": "/orders/123",
       "order_date": 2014-07-03, 
       "product_description": "widget", 
       "sales_rep_name": "Jane Doe",
       "sales_rep_uri": "/salesRep/34"
    },
    {
       "order_num": 456,
       "order_uri": "/orders/456",
       "order_date": 2014-07-04, 
       "product_description": "gadget", 
       "sales_rep_name": "Frank Smith",
       "sales_rep_uri": "/salesRep/53"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is also how I would approach the problem. Note that a GET should never return 201 or 202, since those codes indicate a resource is being created. Use a POST to create the report, and a GET to retrieve the status/report object. You can send a conditional  header in the POST to ensure you don't create a duplicate.

Comment: Good advice, thank you - I'll factor that in to my preliminary design.